# Preserving indentation with Tesseract.js library

Tags: javascript, angular, tesseract, tesseract.js

I am using tessearct.js library in my angular code.
I want to preserve the white spaces, the indentation as it is. How to do it?
Currently I am using this piece of code to do it.

```
async doOCR {
    const worker = createWorker({
      logger: m => console.log(m),
    });
    
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');
    const value = await worker.recognize(this.selectedFile);
  }
```

I am looking a method to do it on client side only, that's why not using its python library.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try after version `(3.04), they have added the` preserve_interword_spaces`. You can try this and check if this works:

```
async doOCR {
    const worker = createWorker({
      logger: m => console.log(m),
    });
    
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');
  // there is no proper documentation, but they have added this flag
  // to run it as a command
    await worker.setParameters({
       preserve_interword_spaces: 1,
    });

    const value = await worker.recognize(this.selectedFile);
  }
```

Comment: The updated version on npmjs is 2.1 only

Comment: So, It might be for python. Have you tried this? There is no proper documentation which says how to use different options.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and its giving error. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'preserve_interword_spaces' does not exist in type 'Partial<WorkerParams>'.

Comment: On updating my angular code,it did work , but is not preserving the white spaces

Comment: 3 years later and no solution as it looks like. The above code executes, but does not lead to the expected results.